# ASP.NET Web APi savechanges problem mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, api

```
upr.Status = "Aktualne";
db.uprawnienia.Add(upr);
db.SaveChanges();
return upr.uprawnienia_id;
```

When i try to add data to database all columns are inserting correctly.

[image]

Id_pracowika is always set to 0

[image]

I can't figure it. I have also no idea why is it happening

Comment: PLease post TEXT/CODE as TEXT and not as a picture of text.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This code is upper. Picture is only to show that data in object is correct.

Comment: Show the entity configuration

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by recreating entity model.